# Odroid-N2 (arm64/aarch64): Initramfs Error after upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, apt, 20.04, upgrade, kernel

i upgraded my older 18.04 LTS version with do-release-upgrade. I had to uninstall mate-desktop to get to the upgrade. Nevertheless, i now get greeded with:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.241-113 aarch64)
```

and meanwhile the upgrade procedure i got the following problem:

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for flash-kernel (3.103ubuntu1~20.04.1) ...
Unsupported platform.
dpkg: error processing package flash-kernel (--configure):
 installed flash-kernel package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-44-generic-64k
Unsupported platform.
```

I not exactly know what happens here, but i think the new kernel version has no arm64 candidate and failed to install? Everything, else had an successful update, despite the kernel? What can i do to get rid of this error, is there any option to tell ubuntu to stick with the old kernel? Are there any pitfalls if i use the new version with an old kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flash-kernel` package version number looks "suspicious". Please note that third party repositories should have been deactivated during the `do-release-upgrade` procedure in your case (see [do-release-upgrade disables third party software sources](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238910/525098) which also explains how you can prevent this in the future).
You'd need to (re-)add the following repository in order to see a modified version of the `flash-kernel` package:

```
[2021-04-29T23:07:52+0200] root@odroid01:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa-linuxfactory-or-kr.list
deb http://ppa.linuxfactory.or.kr focal main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ppa.linuxfactory.or.kr focal main non-free contrib
[2021-04-29T23:08:03+0200] root@odroid01:~# LANG=C apt policy flash-kernel
flash-kernel:
  Installed: 5:3.99+202104021221~focal
  Candidate: 5:3.99+202104021221~focal
[...]
```

Comment: I the meantime i reinstalled the OS using one of the linked version in the hardware kernel wiki